# selecting span - css selectors - Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to select and click on this `<span>`

```
<span class="el-icon 28-0"></span>
```

in the below hierarchy but unable to do so.

```
<div class="list-wrap ng-scope" ng-repeat="d in cols">
            <div class="list-element selected" ng-click="a.cb(d.name, member.name)" ng-class="{selected: (selectValue === d.name || selectValue === member.name + ' ' + d.name)}">
                <span class="el-icon 28-0"></span>
                <!-- ngIf: !d.displayName --><span ng-if="!d.displayName" class="el-text ng-binding ng-scope">
                     28.0 
                </span><!-- end ngIf: !d.displayName -->
                <!-- ngIf: d.displayName -->
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="list-wrap ng-scope" ng-repeat="d in cols">
            <div class="list-element" ng-click="a.cb(d.name, member.name)" ng-class="{selected: (selectValue === d.name || selectValue === member.name + ' ' + d.name)}">
                <span class="el-icon 27-0"></span>
                <!-- ngIf: !d.displayName --><span ng-if="!d.displayName" class="el-text ng-binding ng-scope">


                     27.0 
                </span><!-- end ngIf: !d.displayName -->
                <!-- ngIf: d.displayName -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the page , I am referencing

https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator/?_ga=1.5883444.608313.1428365147#/

In "Browser" section, I am trying to select FF 28.0

I've tried

```
@driver.find_element(:css,"span.el-icon.28-0")
```

BUt it gives

```
The given selector span.el-icon.28-0 is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.
```

Tried this too

```
@driver.find_element(:css,"span.el-text.ng-binding.ng-scope").click
```

which gives

```
 Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Valid CSS classes cannot start with a number.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/2366822)

If changing the class name is not an option for you, try changing the selector to `span.el-icon[class*="28-0"]`

*Note: The 'contains' selector `[class*=...]` matches any elements whose given attribute contains the given value. In this case, any element with a class attribute containing '28-0' would be matched. You could also do this with things like `alt`, `src` or `href` to match external images or links. [Read more here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).*

Comment: thank you for your reply .  It didnt worked exactly like that but I added some code to make it work `element=@driver.find_element(:css,"[class*='28-0']")`     `@driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()" , element) `